# Convert flat List<T> to a List<U> using GroupBy to produce rolled up data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, generics

**UPDATE** I also need to keep the Index of first entry of an employee from `List<T>`in `List<U>` for later use. Currently I am using this code modified from [Nicolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177033/convert-flat-listt-to-a-listu-using-groupby-to-produce-rolled-up-data/28177713#28177713) below

```
List<EmployeeRollup> summary =
      details
      .GroupBy( e => e.EmployeeId , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
      .Select( g => new EmployeeRollup {
        EmployeeId      = g.Key ,
        ProjectDateFrom = g.Min( e => e.ProjectDate ) ,
        ProjectDateThru = g.Max( e => e.ProjectDate ) ,
        FullRecordsRef = employee
                         .FindIndex(f => f.employeeId == g.Key),
        ProjectCodes    = g.Select( e => e.ProjectCode )
                                          .Distinct( StringComparer
                                          .OrdinalIgnoreCase )
                                          .ToArray() ,
      }).ToList();
```

Is this approach correct? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

`<-       End Update   ->`

I have an application where I want to convert a list of objects `List<T>` to another list of objects `List<U>`

The original List (`List<T>`) is `List<Employee>` where `Employee` is defined as

```
class Employee{
  public string empid;
  public Date proj_date;
  public string proj_code;
  // other fields and methods
}
```

and the data in the list looks like

```
empid    proj_date     proj_code 
01     21/Nov/2014       02
01     21/Nov/2014       03
02     21/Nov/2014       09
02     22/Nov/2014       99
02     23/Nov/2014       09
03     21/Nov/2014       15
03     01/Dec/2014       16
```

I want to convert this `List<Employee>` to another List, `List<Emp2>` where `Emp2` is defined as

```
class Emp2{
  public string empid;
  public Date min_proj_date;
  public Date max_proj_date;
  public string [] proj_code;
  // other fields and methods
}
```

After converting from `List<Employee>` the data in `List<Emp2>` should look like the following

```
empid    min_proj_date   max_proj_date  proj_code[] 
01     21/Nov/2014       21/Nov/2014       [02, 03]
02     21/Nov/2014       23/Nov/2014       [09,99]
03     21/Nov/2014       01/Dec/2014       [15,16]
```

So What I am doing is to

- Group by employee_id to get all distinct dates and proj_codes for an employee.
- Get minimum and maximum value of date
- Get distinct values of proj_code as an array

I tried useing `DistinctBy` function from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library) but could not solve the problem.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far as sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much more complex than

```
public class Employee
{
  public string EmployeeId    ;
  public DateTime ProjectDate ;
  public string   ProjectCode ;
}

public class EmployeeRollup
{
  public string EmployeeId        ;
  public DateTime ProjectDateFrom ;
  public DateTime ProjectDateThru ;
  public string[] ProjectCodes    ;
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<Employee>       details = new List<Employee>() ;
    List<EmployeeRollup> summary =
      details
      .GroupBy( e => e.EmployeeId , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
      .Select( g => new EmployeeRollup {
        EmployeeId      = g.Key ,
        ProjectDateFrom = g.Min( e => e.ProjectDate ) ,
        ProjectDateThru = g.Max( e => e.ProjectDate ) ,
        ProjectCodes    = g.Select( e => e.ProjectCode )
                                          .Distinct( StringComparer
                                          .OrdinalIgnoreCase )
                                          .ToArray() ,
      })
      .ToList()
      ;
  }
}
```

If you wanted to track the offset (position) of each `Employee` instance in the original list, you could just do something like this:

```
    List<Employee>       details = new List<Employee>() ;
    int i = 0 ;
    List<EmployeeRollup> summary =
      details
      .Select( e => new KeyValuePair<int,Employee>(i,e) )
      .GroupBy( kvp => kvp.Value.EmployeeId , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
      ...
```

Now you you have a grouping of `KeyValuePair<int,Employee>` where each `KeyValuePair`'s `Key` Property is the integer position within the original list and its `Value` property is the original `Employee` instance.

Just make the changes that fall out from that.

Comment: Is it possible to get the Index of first occurance of each employee i.e `EmployeeId` from `List<Emplyee>` and put it as a field of `List<EmployeeRollup>`

Comment: See my amended answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `GroupBy` and `Select` to convert from one to the other like this:

```
var myEmps = new List<Employee> { /* data here */ };
var myEmp2s = myEmps
    .GroupBy(x => x.empid)
    .Select(x => new Emp2
{
    empid= x.Key,
    min_project_date = x.Min(y => y.proj_date),
    max_project_date = x.Max(y => y.proj_date),
    proj_code = x.Select(y => y.proj_code).ToArray()

    // Other fields are rolled up in a similar fashion as needed
});
```

Comment: He has a groupby in there, not obvious from the question title though.

Comment: Should you have `empid = x.Key` instead of `x.empid`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main approaches. The first is to keep selecting over your initial list with a `list.Select(emp => new { foo = emp.Where(e => e.empid == emp.empid) })`... but this gets computationally bad, and is less idiomatic than... `GroupBy`.

Looks like you also want a few `OrderBy` and `Distinct` clauses, and that by `Date` you probably mean `DateTime`? Otherwise apply adjustments as necessary.

```
var empGroups = emp.GroupBy(e => e.empid);
empGroups.Select(g => new {
    empid = g.Key,
    min_proj_date = g.Min(e => e.proj_date.Date),
    max_proj_date = g.Min(e => e.proj_date.Date),
    proj_code = g.Select(e => e.proj_code).OrderBy(pc => pc).Distinct().ToArray()
})
```

By first grouping, you can operate on the `Key` of the group for future rollups and selects. You then select a new type for the output, and you have a second, inner select on the property itself.

Note the type of the enumeration on a `GroupBy` result is `IGrouping<(string) TKey, (Employee) TElement>` which [inherits from](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `IEnumerable<TElement>`. Once you capture `g` its type is now `IEnumerable<Employee>` plus access to `g.Key`. Treat it as you would any other `IEnumerable` from then out, and use familiar LINQ. This is basically the alternative to instancing a variable, looping, and adding to a list; the variable is defined in and hoisted into your lambda.